# Windows 10 - Unable to convert folder into compressed zip folder

Tags: html, css, node.js, windows-10, zip

Im having an issue that whenever I right click on a folder to compress into a zip folder I recieve this error message... Ive tried searching for the error online but I can't seem to find any fix, Ive attatched the error message. **NOTE**: The files are in fact, NOT opened and I have closed them correctly soo idk..

I would also be open to any softwares that can do the job. I have to compress some webpage code files with FBX animations along with it.

The error is not specific to just this folder, but all that I try.

[CLICK HERE FOR ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB8JT.png)

I've checked this link but nothing

16:27The 10 Safest Free Software Download Sites for Windowswww.makeuseof.com

Ive also tried downloading external compression softwares (Like PeaZip) but as I need to send over some code I dont really trust any of these 3rd party softwares..

As well as that I've tried to compress the folder in my desktop, documents tab etc.. But the same error is recieved.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for **programming** questions. Questions on computer operating systems should be asked in the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) community.